# Neo4j Javascript Driver - date conversion is incorrect by 1 month

Tags: neo4j

With the Neo4j Javascript driver, a stored datetime value of

```
2018-10-22T13:17:02.305000000Z
```

is returning the 64 bit representation as:

```
DateTime {
  year: Integer { low: 2018, high: 0 },
  month: Integer { low: 10, high: 0 },
  day: Integer { low: 22, high: 0 },
  hour: Integer { low: 13, high: 0 },
  minute: Integer { low: 17, high: 0 },
  second: Integer { low: 2, high: 0 },
  nanosecond: Integer { low: 305000000, high: 0 },
  timeZoneOffsetSeconds: Integer { low: 0, high: 0 },
  timeZoneId: null 
}
```

But when converted with moment.js it results in a value of 1 month ahead:

```
2018-11-22T13:17:02.000Z
```

If I try converting the `timestamp` object from 64bit with the Neo4j JS driver:

```
var convert = neo4j.int(timestamp);
```

The `convert` value becomes:

`Integer { low: 0, high: 0 }`

So then `convert.toInt()` , `convert.toString()` and `convert.toString()` all result in the value: `0`

How do I convert a 64 bit datetime into an accurate 32 bit ISO date string with the Neo4j Javascript driver?

Answer (score 0):

When testing with native javascript date conversion, `new Date()`, it returns:

`2018-10-22T13:17:02.305Z`

instead of moment.js which returns:

`2018-11-22T13:17:02.000Z`

So it seems like moment.js might have a bug with 64bit conversion.